# Revolution Slider play only when the slider is visible in the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have two sliders on the page. 
First one is always visible on page load (in the top), second one is at the bottom of the page.

I need to make the second slider start playing only when is visible (on a scroll).
I got [an answer from the developers](http://www.themepunch.com/home/plugins/wordpress-plugins/revolution-slider-wordpress/api-example-pauseresume-the-slider-on-page-scroll/):

```
(function() {
    var win, slider, sliderHeight, sliderPaused, winHeight;

    // Change the "revapi1" part here to whatever "revapi" name that your slider uses
    slider = revapi1.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

        win = jQuery(window).on('scroll', checkScroll).on('resize', sizer);
        sizer();

    });

    function sizer() {
        sliderHeight = slider.height();
        winHeight = win.height();
        checkScroll();
    }

    function checkScroll() {
        var scrTop = win.scrollTop(),
        offset = slider.offset().top;

        if(offset <= scrTop + winHeight && offset + sliderHeight >= scrTop) {

            if(sliderPaused) slider.revresume();
            sliderPaused = false;
        } else {
            if(!sliderPaused) slider.revpause();
            sliderPaused = true;
        }
    }
})();
```

I have tried to use this code (I changed `revapi1` to my slider id already), but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody have a working solution or can help me fix the code I currently have?

Comment: The code you posted looks good, so check your console output for any errors. Otherwise it's pretty hard to tell what's going wrong. At the top of the 'sizer()' function add a line 'console.log('busy with sizer());', so you can check in your console if it is actually being called. If not then it's time to check where you put the above code, which I presume is in the slider's js?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the slider is in the viewport.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  var slidePosition = $("#your-slide").offset().top;

  if (slidePosition < windowPosition) {
    // add code here to play slider
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you pls expline more? Where to put this code? $("#your-slide") is like $("#revapi6")? How can i find it? Or something like: rev_slider_6_2_wrapper? I don't know js.. can help me pls?

Comment: #your-slide is the name of the div that the slider is in. You have to know basic js to implement this.